# Changed a numpy array of string to float but could not get its mean or sum due to unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Tags: arrays, numpy, python-3.6

This is the array that I have which has dtype=object

```
>>> a
array([25.0, 0.0, 0.0, ..., 0.0, 83.3333, 0.0], dtype=object)
```

I tried using the `astype` method to convert the array but got an error:

```
>>> a.astype(float)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

I tried explicitly changing the dtype of each element like this:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    try:
        a[i]=np.float(a[i])
    except:
        print(a[i])
```

It worked fine and nothing got printed.

And then I tried the `astype` method again

```
>>> a.astype(float)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: Maybe you have empty strings in `a`? hence nothing is printed.

Comment: Try replacing the print statement with `print( i, repr(a[i]) )`.  This will show whether there's a problem and where in the array it is.  Empty strings will show as '', not as blanks.

Comment: This worked for me, turns out there were some empty string in the array, causing the issue. Thanks for your help.